# Fix Lumen pagination to starts from zero

Tags: php, laravel, material-ui, lumen

I want to fix the way that Lumen sets the page number. I need that the first page be 0 not 1 like is by default.

So when I call my endpoint `http://localhost:3000/persons?page=0`, the results are like this:

```
class PersonController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $personList = Person::paginate($request->query('per_page') ?? 10);

        return $personList;
    }
}
```

```
{
    "current_page": 1, // this should be 0
    "data": [],
    "first_page_url": "http://localhost:7353/persons?page=1", // i dont need this
    "from": 1, // this should be 0
    "last_page": 31, // this should be 30
    "last_page_url": "http://localhost:7353/persons?page=31", // i dont need this
    "next_page_url": "http://localhost:7353/persons?page=2", // i dont need this
    "path": "http://localhost:7353/persons", // i dont need this
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 310
}
```

This is because I am using the material ui paginator that starts from zero.

```js
<TablePagination
    component='div'
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
    colSpan={3}
    count={this.state.pagination.total}
    rowsPerPage={this.state.pagination.per_page}
    page={this.state.pagination.page}
    onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
    onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage} />
```

The [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/#props) says this about `page` prop:

> The zero-based index of the current page.

I don't want to fix this in javascript by offsetting in all places where I paginate items. So I need the backend return the page zero indexed when `paginate` method be called and as I understand this can be done as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) says, but i cant figure out how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try offsetting the request page:

```
class PersonController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $request->merge([
            'page' => $request->input('page', 0) + 1
        ]);
        $personList = Person::paginate($request->query('per_page') ?? 10);

        return $personList;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to change the json `"current_page": 1,` of the response?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest approach would be to offset it with a middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->query->has('page')) {
        $request->merge([
            'page' => $request->query->get('page') + 1
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Register it and call it on your routes.

```
Route::get('persons', 'PersonController@index')->middleware('offset-pagination');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the Laravel way, but the starting page (1) was hardcoded in a lot of files and highly coupled. So I ended up fixing a lot of code:

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->bind(
    Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::class,
    App\PaginationFix\LengthAwarePaginator::class
);

// some code

$app->register(App\PaginationFix\PaginationServiceProvider::class);
```

**PaginationServiceProvider.php**, original [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.7.0/src/Illuminate/Pagination/PaginationServiceProvider.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\PaginationFix;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PaginationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // set page resolver
        Paginator::currentPageResolver(function ($pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $this->app['request']->input($pageName);

            if (filter_var($page, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false && (int) $page >= 0) {
                return (int) $page;
            }

            return 0;
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

**Person.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Person extends Model
{
    // model code
}
```

**Model.php**, original [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.7.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1039)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;
use App\PaginationFix\Builder;

class Model extends EloquentModel
{
    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        return new Builder($query);
    }
}
```

The query **Builder.php**, original [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.7.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L698)

```
<?php

namespace App\PaginationFix;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as EloquentBuilder;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class Builder extends EloquentBuilder
{
    public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
    {
        $page = $page ?: Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

        $perPage = $perPage ?: $this->model->getPerPage();

        $results = ($total = $this->toBase()->getCountForPagination()) 
                   ? $this->skip($page * $perPage)->take($perPage)->get($columns) 
                   : $this->model->newCollection();

        return $this->paginator($results, $total, $perPage, $page, [
            'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
            'pageName' => $pageName,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**LengthAwarePaginator.php**, original [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v6.7.0/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\PaginationFix;

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as IlluminateLengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class LengthAwarePaginator extends IlluminateLengthAwarePaginator
{
    public function __construct($items, $total, $perPage, $currentPage = null, array $options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($items, $total, $perPage, $currentPage, $options);

        $this->lastPage = max((int) floor($total / $perPage), 0);
    }

    protected function setCurrentPage($currentPage, $pageName)
    {
        $currentPage = $currentPage ?: static::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

        return $this->isValidPageNumber($currentPage) ? (int) $currentPage : 0;
    }

    protected function isValidPageNumber($page)
    {
        return $page >= 0 && filter_var($page, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false;
    }

    public function previousPageUrl()
    {
        if ($this->currentPage() > 0) {
            return $this->url($this->currentPage() - 1);
        }
    }

    public function url($page)
    {
        if ($page < 0) {
            $page = 0;
        }

        $parameters = [$this->pageName => $page];

        if (count($this->query) > 0) {
            $parameters = array_merge($this->query, $parameters);
        }

        return $this->path()
        . (Str::contains($this->path(), '?') ? '&' : '?')
        . Arr::query($parameters)
        . $this->buildFragment();
    }

    public function firstItem()
    {
        return count($this->items) > 0 ? ($this->currentPage) * $this->perPage + 1 : null;
    }

    public function lastItem()
    {
        return count($this->items) > 0 ? $this->firstItem() + $this->count() - 1 : null;
    }

    public function hasPages()
    {
        return $this->currentPage() != 0 || $this->hasMorePages();
    }

    public function onFirstPage()
    {
        return $this->currentPage() <= 0;
    }

    public static function resolveCurrentPage($pageName = 'page', $default = 0)
    {
        if (isset(static::$currentPageResolver)) {
            return call_user_func(static::$currentPageResolver, $pageName);
        }

        return $default;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
            'data' => $this->items->toArray(),
            'from' => $this->firstItem(),
            'last_page' => $this->lastPage(),
            'per_page' => $this->perPage(),
            'to' => $this->lastItem(),
            'total' => $this->total(),
        ];
    }
}
```